# Count(s), as in the legal definition of count, in Japanese

Tags: english-to-japanese, law

How would you say "count" as in the legal term counting up the number of legal charges against a person? Or, rather, what is the counter word for a number of legal charges in Japanese? Is it a word like 度 or something?

Comment: > "as in the legal term counting up the number of legal charges against a person?" I think you should provide more concrete context. What is the aim of the document and what exactly do you need to explain? What do you mean by *legal definition of* count?

Comment: @Yosh:  "The criminal was convicted on two ***counts*** of aggravated assault and one ***count*** of armed robbery".
JustinSewell:  I see [訴因]{そ・いん} in my dictionary, but I don't know how correct or common that is.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's 件.

For example, taking from [here](https://settou-bengosi.com/kenrenhan-heigozai-sukusukaisetto-ryokei-keijisenmonbengoshi/)

> Ａさんが罪に問われる可能性があるのは、5件の窃盗罪と、それぞれの窃盗で被害者宅の庭に侵入しているため、5件の住居侵入罪です

Likewise, 彼は2件の殺人について起訴された means *He was charged with two counts of murder*.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. Since "件" means "cases/incidences" it kinda translates to "two incidences of xyz" and whatnot. Thank you!